# PHP Syntax and Reasoning with Date If/Else Statement

Tags: php, optimization, syntax

I am working on a project and I have encountered this code:

```
$year    = date('Y') - (date('n') > 9 ? 0 : 1);
```

The way I read it, it seems to be; if the year (2014) minus the month (12) is greater than 9, then the Boolean is False, Otherwise it is true.

However when I go to print the variable, it prints 2014. I then changed 9 to 9000 to see what would happen, and it changed to 2013. I know this sound rudimentary but I can't understand why and I wasn't able to immediately find on google how this makes sense.

EDIT: Sorry, there was a leftover parentheses at the end of the code that wasn't supposed to be there. The code has been edited.

Comment: date('n') is not the month ... date('**m**') stands for month

Comment: Parentheses aren't just there to look pretty. Remember BODMAS (or your school's equivalent acronym)

Comment: You're not reading it properly, you're currently doing: Year - (is date('n') higher than 9? if so, 0, else, 1) .

Comment: @donald123 `n` is the months without leading zero - works better for casting to a number.

Comment: It returns current year if month is Oct, Nov or Dec; it returns previous year otherwise.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol ... you're right in my mind i has **N** for n .. all is fine

Comment: Ahhhh Youre Right! I just saw it!

Comment: Mind explaining us what you EXACTLY want to accomplish? the output of your code is correct (before you edited it), what are you looking for?

Comment: OP: Please clarify what your goal is! What is your question?!

Comment: @Rizier123 my original question was regarding the boolean, but I was looking at the problem incorrectly, and the numbers aren't booleans, but integers to be subtracted pending if the statement is true.

Comment: @briosheje I changed it back, I figured it out, it wasn't a boolean, but integers

Comment: Ok, but the question is still not clear. I didn't really get what you were looking for, I just knew (and wrote above) that you didn't interprete your code correctly.

Comment: @CodeNewby Do you have still a question? If not you code write your own answer and explain what the solution was! Otherwise say: This is what i'm looking for, This is what i'm getting and This is what i have tried...

Comment: @briosheje upon beating my head in, I kept seeing the code as if Date Year minus Date Month is greater than 9, then False, else True. I treated 1 and 0 as booleans. The question was how was that string of code logically getting 2014 or 2013. I didnt notice the extra parentheses and realized that the 0:1 were integers to be subtracted from the year. Its dealing with Fiscal years, which explains the 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the function calls of `date()` your code would look like this:

```
$year    = 2014 - (12 > 9 ? 0 : 1);
```

Now you may see better that 12 is greater then 9 and it is TRUE! So 0 get's 'used':

```
$year    = 2014 - 0;
```

So the result is:

```
2014
```

Your adoption is wrong that the ternary operator condition is false!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a formula for getting the fiscal year.  The parenthetical evaluates to 0 if the month is Oct-Dec, 1 otherwise.  So it subtracts 1 from the current year unless the date is after Sep 30.

Comment: What exactly is a fiscal year?

Comment: @SalmanA When budgets are recalculated, right around September/October

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you noticed the extra paranthesis around the second date parameter.

You're reading the code like this:

```
date('Y') - date('n')
```

But, the code actually says:

```
data('Y') - 1 // or 0 (depending on the returned int from the ternary operation)
```

Another way to write it is:

```
$dateX = date('Y');
$dateY = (date('n') > 9 ? 0 : 1);
$result = $dateX-$dateY;
// result will output either 2014 (from $dateX) or 2013 (if $dateY equals 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
 $year    = (date('Y') - (date('n')) > 9 ? "false" : "true");
 echo $year; //this will give you false.
```

Or like this,

```
 $year    = (date('Y') - (date('n')) > 9 ? 0 : 1);
 echo $year; //this will give you 0.
```